# 1+1D Dirac Hamiltonian - Interpretation of "hopping" term

Tags: field-theory, hamiltonian, fermions

Consider the classic 1+1D Dirac Hamiltonian:
\begin{align}
H = -i\left[\psi_L^\dagger \partial_x \psi_L - \psi_R^\dagger \partial_x \psi_R\right] + m\left(\psi_L^\dagger\psi_R - \psi_R^\dagger \psi_L\right)
\end{align}
where we have expanded out the typical 2-component Dirac spinor into chiral pieces $\psi_L, \psi_R$. As suggestively written, the second term on the right corresponds to opening a mass gap of $2m$ at the Fermi surface; this is simply the Dirac mass. What does the sum of "left-right" hopping terms $\psi_L^\dagger\psi_R + \psi_R^\dagger \psi_L$ mean? Is there a simple physical interpretation of what this term does?